# Visual editing of graphical objects in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, drawing, editing

There is a graphics WPF editor that is designed to work with diagrams. Because diagram can consist of very large number of objects, it was chosen to use Drawings for output. That means we create list of some business objects

```
class BusinessObject
{
   // bunch of other properties and methods
   public GeometryDrawing MyDrawing {get;set;}
}
```

pass it to helper that creates DrawingVisual for each drawing :

```
public List<Visual> BuildVisuals(List<BusinessObject> objectsList)
{
   // foreach item in objectsList takes item.MyDrawing and draws it with DrawingContext
}
```

and then inject received data into drawing host

```
public class VisualHost : FrameworkElement
{
   // FrameworkElement overrides, skipped

   public readonly VisualCollection _children;       

   public VisualHost(List<Visual> visualsList)
   {
     _children = new VisualCollection(this);
     foreach(var visual in visualsList)
     {
        _children.Add(visual);
     }
     // mouse handlers, other logic (skipped)
   }
}
```

Everything works fine and quickly (even VisualHitTesting with backward mapping to respective business object with two-way data changing on-the-fly), but now there is a need to allow visual editing of objects - moving them around workspace, change size, scale ratio, etc. WPF Thumbs and Adorners come into mind (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part1.aspx), but they are intended to work with UIElement/Controls, that our Visuals aren't. Does anyone see a way to solve this problem without much changes of initial logic? Some workarounds or similiar functionality maybe. Rewriting the above mentioned code is not an option, we can't have 1000+ Control objects in memory if we use them on diagram. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create some kind of optimization that when a FrameworkElement receives mouse focus, wrap it in a UIElement or Control, then when it loses, back to FrameworkElement..?

Comment: Thought about it... But wrapping FE itself will not give anything, because i need to adorn its children, not the whole picture altogether.

Comment: So, you have a container (e.g. Window), which has a single `MultiDrawingVisualHost` or many `MultiDrawingVisualHost`? Or is the the `MultiDrawingVisualHost` the only host, and it has the 1000's of objects? Please define the problem a bit better.

Comment: I have second scenario - VisualHost represents a diagram, visuals built from drawings are diagram elements i need to work with. Added more VisualHost class code.

Comment: Is this possible: Your `VisualHost` object accepts (user) input, such as mouse events. Also, you can obtain the mouse coordinates of all `Visual _children` objects.  So, maybe it's possible that when the mouse pointer is within or near a Visual child's coordinates, you temporarily "wrap" that or those Visuals into a `UIElement` (or something the user can work with) with element having the adorners.  So, you really only ever have 1 or a very small number of `UIElements`.  (As the mouse gets farther away, you transfer the UIElements back to Visuals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved manually - resizing and rotating adorners were drawn as separate objects over existing ones and added/removed from canvas on set/lost focus.